# Reactive Form Data Binding with Angular Service

Tags: angular, angular-services, reactive, angular-service-worker

I have 5 forms so I am implementing data service to connect them. Service working fine and I am getting data in service but when I will go from one page to the second page and click on next them I will only get second form data but I want first form data also
So that in final stage I can send all collected data to API.
this is the my code

```
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';`
`import { AddBusinessMutation} from 'src/app/graphql'`
`import{FormGroup, FormControl, Validators,FormArray} from '@angular/forms'`

`@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})`
`export class AddbusinessService {`
    `business: AddBusinessMutation;`
    `businesses: [];`
    `setGeneralFormData(data) {`
        `// this.businesses = data.socialLinks;
        // this.business = data.frmData;`
        `console.log(data)
    }`
`constructor(){`
    `}`
`}`
```

Comment: Are you want the 5 forms data in the same object or in array of 5 items?

Comment: this.business = data.frmData; -< here you rewrite your array with data. Maybe this.business.push(data.frmData); you need?

Comment: ya i want all these data in same object

Comment: @PrateekPareek Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should push every form data to `businesses` array and append new properties to `business` object

```
business: AddBusinessMutation;
businesses: any[] = [];
setGeneralFormData(data) {
  this.businesses.push(data.socialLinks)
  this.business = <AddBusinessMutation> Object.assign({}, this.business, data.frmData)
  console.log(data);
}
```

instead of

```
setGeneralFormData(data) {
  this.businesses = data.socialLinks;
  this.business = data.frmData;
  console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: i am getting this  error  Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Comment: I edited the answer, If still exists please tell me on which line

Comment: ya error is still there i am getting error in second line this.businesses.push(data.socialLinks)    .

Comment: I  edited the answer again, but I need to double check is `data.soicalLinks` are `any` type right?

Comment: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined i am getting this error in my console

Comment: Sorry We forgot to initialize the `businesses` array, check now

Comment: now i want that when i come back from form  2 to 1 my form data should no to be empty . i want to show the data that user fill before going to step 2

Comment: You can use the `addbusinessService.business` from component to prefill the step 1, Are you got it or not?, If not ask me for more details

Comment: i did not got please can you explain from scratch I am bigginer

Comment: To be able to navigate to from your multiple steps forms
You need to save the each step data in object in your service `business` object
for example:

First form properties is `(A, B and C)`
and you move to next step, You will save them in your service in object `business` so `business` object will have the properties `(A, B and C)`
When you back to step 1 again you should get the step 1 properties from `business` object (from your services) and prefill the step 1 form with his properties `(A, B and C)` properties

Comment: You need to get form properties from your `business` object  before initialize the current step form if the `business` object has the current step form properties

Comment: how i will access the busineeses data I am getting data in object in array businesses and the order of json is not will also there is 5 json file

Comment: You need to declare the `business` object with `public` modifier in your service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217522/discussion-between-prateek-pareek-and-abdelrhman-elsayed).

Answer (score 1):

you can use state managment to store form data

https://netbasal.com/connect-angular-forms-to-ngrx-store-c495d17e129